# Prove that autocompatible LCPT maps are antidegradable

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory

> A LCPT map $\Phi$ is antidegradable if and only if it is compatible with itself.

The proof that an antidegradable map (satisfying $\Phi=\Lambda_E\circ \tilde\Phi$ where $\tilde\Phi$ is the complementary map and $\Lambda:\mathscr S(\mathcal H_E)\to \mathscr S(\mathcal H_S)$ is an LCPT map)  is autocompatible is pretty easy: just consider the operator $$ \Psi=(\mathbb I_S\otimes\Lambda_E)\circ(U_{SE}(\rho_S\otimes\tau_E)U_{SE}^\dagger)$$ and notice that $\Phi=\text{tr}_S[\Psi]=\text{tr}_E[\Psi]$. Is there a simple proof for the reverse implication?

Comment: Maybe it would be good to define some of the terms in this question, e.g., antidegradable, autocompatible / compatible and I assume LCPT is linear, completely positive and trace preserving?

Comment: @Rammus Sorry, I thought all of this was standard. LCPT is indeed linear, completely positive and trace-preserving; an antidegradable map, as I have written, is a map that satisfies $\Phi=\Lambda_E\circ\tilde\Phi$ for some LCPT map $\Lambda_E$. Finally two maps $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are compatible if there exists a LCPT map $\Psi$ such that $\Phi_1=\text{tr}_2[\Psi]$ and $\Phi_2=\text{tr}_1[\Psi]$.

Comment: What does 'complementary' mean exactly?